# How to recover multiplication of group elements from category of groups?

Tags: category-theory

Motivating question: If we know everything about $\mathbf{Grp}$, do we know everything about groups?

Background: Consider the category $\mathbf{Grp}$ abstractly, rather than as a concrete category.  The elements of a group $G$ may be recovered as follows: first, identify the group $\mathcal{Z}$ as the unique minimal generator ([MO/7793](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7793/what-are-the-auto-equivalences-of-the-category-of-groups)), i.e. a [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(category_theory)) such that no proper quotient is also a generator.    Then Hom($\mathbb{Z}$,-) represents the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Set}$ and recovers the elements of group.

Question:

> How can you also recover the group operation on elements?

Here is an unfinished attempt (that [someone else mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/users/27013/tobias-fritz)): define the free group on two generators by the coproduct $F_2 = \mathbb{Z} \amalg \mathbb{Z}$.  Then for two group elements $g_1, g_2 : \mathbb{Z} \to G$, these maps will define a map $f :  F_2 \to G$ (because $F_2$ is a colimit).  Finally, *suppose* we could categorically specify the map $m : \mathbb{Z} \to F_2, 1 \mapsto xy$, where $x,y$ are the generators of $F_2$.  Then the group multiplication of the elements $g_1, g_2$ would yield the element $g_1 g_2 = f \cdot m : \mathbb{Z} \to G$.

In the above approach, the only remaining task is to somehow specify the map $m : \mathbb{Z} \to F_2, 1 \mapsto xy$ categorically.

**Edit** (in response to comment):

I should mention that we will not be able to distinguish $m : \mathbb{Z} \to F_2, 1 \mapsto xy$ from $m' : 1 \mapsto yx$.  The best we can hope for is to specify both $m$ and $m'$ without singling either of them out.  In other words, when we attempt to recover group multiplication, we can provide a choice of either the original group multiplication or multiplication in the opposite group, but we cannot privilege either choice.  The reason is that the functor sending a group to its opposite group is an auto-equivalence of $\mathbf{Grp}$.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to distinguish $1 \mapsto x y$ from $1 \mapsto y x$.

Comment: Good point; I've modified the question to include an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have $\mathbb{Z}$, you have the [Lawvere theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawvere_theory) of groups (which can be recovered as the opposite category on the full subcategory on the finite coproducts of $\mathbb{Z}$), which is a way of axiomatizing what a group is that doesn't depend on a choice of "generators." What I mean by this is that multiplication, inversion, and unit can be composed to get a lot of other operations, such as

$$(x, y, z) \mapsto x^{-3} y z^4 y^3$$

which satisfy some relations, and the Lawvere theory of groups packages up all of this information (the above operation is, after all, the same thing as a particular element of $F_3$) without privileging a particular choice of generating operations, in the same way that you can specify a group itself in a way that doesn't privilege a particular presentation. See, for example, [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/a-less-biased-definition-of-a-group/) and [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/operations-and-lawvere-theories/) for some details.

Comment: The question could equally well be asked of the Lawvere theory of groups: given the Lawvere theory of groups as an abstract Lawvere theory, is there a way to recognise $(x, y) \mapsto x y$?

Comment: @Zhen: sure, but I'm trying to address the motivating question. My claim is that the Lawvere theory of groups already constitutes "everything about groups." I agree that there's still an interesting additional question remaining.